# schedule event in class oriented plugin

Tags: hooks, actions

Actions usually support the following (if you are creating your plugin using a class based approach):

```
add_action('admin_notices', array(&$this, 'emailNoticeGUI'));
```

The `wp_schedule_event` does not support this kind of triggering. Is there any way I could do this, but still use a class based approach? What are the alternatives? I would like to schedule a hook upon plugin activation, but the activation logic is also based in the class itself.

Comment: Please check [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) this may help you.

Comment: I am sorry but if something isn't working for you it does not mean it does not support.
Share your code what you done so far then only someone can help you.

Comment: I solved it by using an action and then used that action in the `wp_schedule_event_function`.

Answer (score 0):

This reason, and others (removing a hook for example) is why you should use for hooks only plain functions or static functions.

OOP in plugins and themes rarely has anything to do with proper OO. If you use it as a way to have a separate namespace, then just use a namespace.

Comment: I think that today we are way beyond the days where you have a million functions following each other. I use OO because it improves readablity. Sure, functions are good for smaller plugins, but when you have a big one that reaches 5000+ LOC, then I think OO is the way to go.

Comment: @ZeroCool, really? so why is this question that you had to ask which show luck of understanding of OOP principals? OOP is not just declaring classes, and done wrong it at best just makes your code longer. you are welcom to read this chat thread - http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27197907#27197907

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used was the following:

```
add_action('my_action', array(&$this, 'classFunctionName'));
```

When scheduling I used the following:

```
 wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_action');
```

So the `classFunctionName` is triggered on a daily basis and it is called from within the plugin class.